# Is it possible to view TSconfig in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

It is possible to look at existing TypoScript (TypoScript object browser), TCA, Global Configuration etc. in the backend. I am wondering if it is possible to do the same with TSconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it in the "Information" module by selecting "Page TSconfig" in the dropdown.

[image]